# javascript iterate through dom looking for specific aria-label

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes

I've spent hours on this one.

My company is forced to use a non-user-friendly 3rd party website. We only use IE11. My job is to use javascript and jquery to customize the screen and make things a little easier for our users. I use a bookmarklet to insert `<script>` tags into IE and reference a .js file saved locally.

This website uses hundreds of input text fields but we only need a handful of them. So, I want to highlight input text fields on the screen.
Some fields have ID's some only have Name. For the most part, this works:

`$(document.getElementById('s_3_1_18_0').toggleClass("highlightField");`
`$(document.getElementsByName('s_3_1_19_0')[0]).toggleClass("highlightField");`

HighlightField simply adds CSS `background-color: yellow !important`

The problem is, this 3rd party app changes the ID and the Name in bizarre ways. One day, the name will be 's_3_1_19_0', the next it will be 's_3_2_48_0'. So highlighting using this method is not stable.

However, these fields have an area-label that stays constant. I'm wondering how to use javascript or jquery to iterate through each text box, looking for a specific aria-label. For example, the "valid to" field has a bizarre name that changes all the time but it's aria-label is always "Valid To".

Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the input with the aria-label "Valid To" by searching for

```
$(document).find('input').attr('aria-label', 'Valid To');
```

I recommend being a little bit more specific than `$(document)`, though. That searches the entire doc.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much. The final code:
`$(document).find('input').attr('aria-label', 'Valid To').toggleClass("highlightField");

Comment: Glad to hear it! I'd be grateful if you could accept my answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery to get the list of all aria-label attributes and use a switch case to perform what you need. Something like this
    `switch ($(this).attr('aria-label')) {
      case 'label1': {
      //do something
      break;
      }
    }`